# How to make a order in salesforce using php

Tags: salesforce1-app, php, datatable, order, orderitem

I'm tried to insert or create new order like product and shipping details in salesforce,but i got get the exact table name for create order please help me name of the table i need to use and what parameter need to send..i tried some table name to select filed i referred in link

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api/Content/sforce_api_objects_orderitem.htm

```
$query = "SELECT PricebookEntryId,OrderId,UnitPrice,ServiceDate,Quantity FROM OrderItem"; 
        $response = $this->salesforce->query($query);
```

but not working show error,please help me.. thx in advc

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to SF.SE Raj. You may find the [Object Reference](http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/object_reference/object_reference.pdf) to be a useful resource in sorting out your coding. Normally, when creating a new record, one does an insert. The order of the fields within a list for an object isn't critical so long as all the values for `required` fields are included.

Be aware that what's required can vary from Org to Org, particularly when custom fields have been added. Without knowing the schema for your org, its difficult to say exactly what problem you're encountering. You may want to try running a SOQL query from the Developer Console.

If you have Ajax Tools installed or use [Workbench](https://workbench.developerforce.com/login.php), you can also "explore" your org to see all the relationships between your objects which may help you sort out your problem, including discovering the names of all fields required to insert a new record.

Answer (score 1):

I think the best option for placing an order in Salesforce from PHP is the Place Order REST API:

http://www.salesforce.com/us/developer/docs/api_placeorder/salesforce_placeorder_rest_api.pdf

Your PHP application will need to authenticate against Salesforce first using either an OAuth Webserver, User-Agent or Username-Password flows prior to posting your order in a separate callout.